# CPP Prime Generator SPOJ Sieve

Tags: c++, sieve

I did implement Sieve prime generator. The code is pretty fast and consumes less memory. https://www.spoj.com/problems/PRIME1/

But I get "Wrong Answer" when I submit the solution. People online seem to just make the set the max to 32000 and run the solution. I don't exactly get where am I actually wrong? Or Is it just an extra `newline` (if possible) that makes the solution to be incorrect?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

int main(void) {

  unordered_map<long long int, bool> notPrime;
  notPrime[0] = true;
  notPrime[1] = true;
  for (long long int x = 2; x < 100000; x++) {
    if (notPrime[x]) continue;
    for (long long int u = 2 * x; u < 100000; u += x)
      notPrime[u] = true;

  }

  int n;
  cin >> n;

  while (n--) {
    long long int s, e;
    cin >> s >> e;

    if (s < 0)
      s = 0;

    for (long long int i = s; i <= e; i++) {
      if (!notPrime[i]) {
    cout << i << '\n';
      }
    }

    if (n)
      puts("");

  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please edit your post with the results of your debugging session.

Comment: All numbers greater than 100000 are prime?

Comment: `In each of the next t lines there are two numbers m and n (1 <= m <= n <= 1000000000, n-m<=100000) separated by a space.` Your maps covers up to 99999 value, but it should up to 1000000000.

Comment: a hint: your memory limit is 1536MB, so use `std::vector<bool>` it will require 1000000000 / 8 = 125000000 bytes, which is 119MB